# Question on sed command?

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to use sed to delete parts of a text file with lines like:

> 23920   E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:5 ch 80  7279  1113  5272  -342  1168  5642  -347  1265  5587
>
> 23921   E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:6 ch 1  4605  1267  4586  11  1331  4587  -31  1306  4692

The parts I need to delete are the parts like `E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:5 ch 80` and `E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:6 ch 1` in every line. The numbers change throughout the file, but are always between 1 and 100.

Comment: Is it always the same 7 fields that you need to remove?

Comment: @Jed: good point, and if the answer is yes, `awk` may be a better (or at least more optimized) tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `cut` for this, if it always the same fields:

```
jed@jed-osx:~$ echo "23920 E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:5 ch 80 7279 1113 5272 -342 1168 5642 -347 1265 5587
23921 E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:6 ch 1 4605 1267 4586 11 1331 4587 -31 1306 4692" | cut -d" " -f1,8-
23920 80 7279 1113 5272 -342 1168 5642 -347 1265 5587
23921 1 4605 1267 4586 11 1331 4587 -31 1306 4692
```

EDIT: Explanation of the cut command used:

`-d" "`  Use space as the delimiter

`-f 1,8-`  Return field 1, field 8, and all fields after 8

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution

```
linux-t77m:$ more st.txt
23920 E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:5 ch 80 7279 1113 5272 -342 1168 5642 -347 1265 5587

23921 E S:1 R:2 C:14 L:6 ch 1 4605 1267 4586 11 1331 4587 -31 1306 4692

linux-t77m:$ sed -r "s/E S:.* ch [0-9]+ //g" st.txt
23920 7279 1113 5272 -342 1168 5642 -347 1265 5587

23921 4605 1267 4586 11 1331 4587 -31 1306 4692
```

This is done with a regular expression substitution. The command s/<regexp>/<substitution>/g replaces every part of every line matching <regexp> for <substitution>.

In this case <regexp> is `E S:.* ch [0-9]+` which means:

1. search for E S:
2. then seach for everything until you see
3. a space preceding ch followed by a space, one or more digits and another space

And <substitution> is the empty string, so it effectively deletes the parts of the lines matching it.

The -r switch signals sed we are using an 'extended' regular expressions, which are usually clearer because they don't need so many backslashes which standard sed regexps would require.

Comment: Can you explain what each part of the sed command above does? This way we can all learn instead of relying on sed masters like you for each variation. I have to admit I was guilty of not explaining my cut command, so I edited and added the explanation, but sed is much more complicated.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic, note that the `-r` option is a GNU sed ism, and is neither standard nor universal. A better modern approach would be the `-E` option, but even that's not universal. The best approach would be to use BRE, which will work in all versions of sed.